# `setCookie()` that Slim framework provides will not work if I use `exit()` after it

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, slim

I need to use an ajax request to perform login. Here's the function that request goes to:

```
function loginAdmin() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if (auth()) {
        $app->setCookie('admin', TRUE);
        exit(TRUE);
    }
    exit(NULL);
}
```

And I will process the ajax response to see if it's true. But the cookie wouldn't be set. If I remove `exit(TRUE)` the cookie can be set.

I've read the source code of Slim, the `setCookie()` function calls `\Slim\Http\Cookies::setCookie()`, which set the key and value into `$data` member. But I'm not sure when the cookies are sent.

But I still don't know how does `exit` function affect `setCookie` function.

Comment: Why do you need to `exit` in the first place?

Comment: Because it's an ajax call, and I need a response back to the client to know if the login action succeeds.

Comment: @deceze But why does `exit()` affect `setCookie()`? Strange to me

Comment: I don't know Slim, but a) I guess `setCookie` collects a header in an array, but only actually outputs it at the end somewhere when the response is flushed to the client and b) Slim probably has an explicit method to send a positive or negative response to the client other than `exit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send response using `exit()`. You should `echo()` the response in the route. For example something like:

```
function loginAdmin() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if (auth()) {
        $app->setCookie('admin', TRUE);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

$app->get('/foo', function {
    echo loginAdmin();
});
```

Above code is not a good way to do authentication, but it shows the point.

Comment: Why is that? PHP documentation says exit(something) is just echo something then exit. Other functions are okay with this approach.

Comment: Probably because Slim buffers all output. Calling exit() will kill PHP before Slim has time to flush output buffer. Using exit() is quite unorthodox anyway.